# DWMEnableBlurBehind makes my interface controls semi transparent

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have enabled blur on my window. I have some edit fields and some custom controls and I would not want these to be affected by the blur, they are semi transparent as a result. How could I only blur the main window itself, not its child controls (sort of like Chrome). Thanks

Comment: [This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/01/23/controls-and-the-desktop-window-manager.aspx) discusses exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black is treated as transparent since good old GDI does not support alpha channel (the alpha byte in ARGB is always 0) I'm thinking you have to do some sort of [owner draw](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/01/23/controls-and-the-desktop-window-manager.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try to make windows style WS_CLIPCHILDREN